# Why is AliasMatch not working?

Tags: apache

Here is what we have:

```
 Alias /assets/ "/home/virtual/public_assets/"
 AliasMatch ^/~([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/assets/(.*)$ /home/virtual/public_assets/$2

 <Directory "/home/virtual/public_assets">
      AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Here is the URI we are trying to match to:

```
 /~admin30/assets/js/tests.js
```

The `Alias` directive works for our live sites, however, the `AliasMatch` which is supposed to match user directories does not.

Comment: if you have enabled the userdir directive, try to disable it

Comment: Why not use a cleaner conditional rewrite using htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your configuration and it works fine on a clean Apache install. It is possible you have other conflicting configuration somewhere.

I would also test it with a single user in the `AliasMatch` directive rather than the generic pattern you currently have. Like this:

```
 AliasMatch ^/~admin30/assets/(.*)$ /home/virtual/public_assets/$1
```

Also if you could describe what does actually happens it might help. If you get an error, check the Apache error log and show us any relevant entries.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to put your AliasMatch directive before the alias directive. I think it works best to have the most specific paths first.